# Is a packet duplicated when sent across multiple stations in OmNeT++/INet?

Tags: omnet++, inet

With particular regards to [`Ieee80211` in INet](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/tree/5c6ea92f4e503c381310952eeee4ecbb8f702d38/src/inet/linklayer/ieee80211) library, I have a question about what happens when a `cPacket`/`cMessage` is sent across multiple stations.

It is possible that this is not strictly about INet, but a general behavior of [OmNet++](https://omnetpp.org/). Here's the question:

> When sending a `cPacket`/`cMessage` and it is received by multiple stations/modules, is it copied or all receivers get a pointer to the same instance?

#### Real scenario

So, in such a network:

[image]

Station `A` is sending a `cMessage` which is received by all the other stations. Of course only one station is the receiver, everyone else will drop the packet. So if `B` is the receiver and `C`, `D`, `E` and `F` go:

```
void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
  if (this->isNotForUs())
    delete msg;
}
```

Will it cause `B` to have its frame destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `OMNeT++/INET` sending a `cMessage` to multiple receivers is modelled by creating multiple copies of this message and sending one copy to one receiver. There is `dup()` method that creates an exact copy of the message. For example:

```
cMessage *msg2 = msg->dup();
```

As a consequence, every receiver will receive a new instance of `cMessage` object, and it can remove or process it in any way. Therefore, in your example deleting a message by `C`,`D`,`E`, and `F` does not affect the message received by `B`.

Comment: Thanks for the very simple and easy to understand answer :)